# I have upload my application to Apple store. App requires Username/Password to Proceed Where i send these details in ituneconnect?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have upload my application to Apple store. App requires Username/Password to Proceed Where i send these details in ituneconnect? How apple review team login to app when app in review process?

Comment: Not clear about your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to say that your app requires a username and password and you want to know where to provide these so that Apple's reviewer can login and review the app properly?

If so, there is a section at the bottom called "Demo Account" that has Username and Password fields for this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks something like this in your itunesConnect under DemoAccount section inside MyApps-> YourAppDetails.

[image]